# Dropdown menu not working on iPad with top level links

Tags: jquery, ipad, drop-down-menu, menu, cs-cart

So I have a client whose website uses cs-cart. The top menu consist of a handful of dropdown menus, the top level item here is a link itself too.

When I click on the top level item, the dropdown shows, however it clicks the link too and goes to that page, making it impossible to click on the items in the dropdown.

(It seems to only happen for the first 5-6 top menu items too.. the last 3 seem ok?..)

Further to this, when I do try and click on the dropdown menu items, it clicks on the banner behind it.. so still cant use it.

I've added modernizer and tried a couple of javascript fixes, but none seem to work.

Anyone know what else I can do?

Site: http://bit.ly/Mu5kbR

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
if ( modernizr.touch ) {
    $('a.drop').click(function(e) {
       var next = $(this).next("div");
       if ( next.not(":visible") ) {
         e.preventDefault();
         next.show();
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: I still need users to be able to click on the link in the menu too, I'll adapt by adding a class which can be toggled for this.. let me try it.

Comment: Thanks, worked, I didnt have the 'touch' in my modernizer before so it didnt fire, but got that, thanks a lot

Comment: @RichardEdwards I've edited my answer to include the ability to click the top level menu item, once it's drop down menu is visible.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to change dropdown action from hover to click on first level for all the touch devices

Comment: That would show the dropdown when I click rather than hover yes. But it does not stop the person clicking on the top level link and being taken to that page INSTEAD of showing the dropdown.